# Rails simple_form: custom input id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to put several forms generated with Rails simple_form on a one page, and operate on them with javascript. However simple_form generated same ids for respective inputs in forms. Thus I want to replace generated id with my own.

Now I have a line:

```
<%= f.input :id, :as => :hidden, :html => {:value => @question.id} %>
```

and HTML output (for @question.id=1):

```
<input id="question_id" class="hidden" type="hidden" value="1" name="question[id]">
```

and I want to get:

```
<input id="question_id_1" class="hidden" type="hidden" value="1" name="question[id]">
```

`question_id_1` is just an example. I want to be able to choose this id.

I use Rails 3 and simple_form 1.5.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're almost there.

The trick is in specifying the `:input_html`.

```
<%= f.input :id, :as => :hidden,
      :input_html => {
        :value => @question.id,
        :id => "question_id_1"
      } %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried, `:html` and `:html_options`, but `:input_html` solves the problem.

Comment: :input_html, :label_html, :wrapper_html will cover most of these things.