# Rails Simple Form Update a Div based on Select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to update a text in a div with the value that the user selects in a dropdown list, using Simple Form on Rails5. It should work like this, but I can't get it to work in Simple Form: http://jsfiddle.net/zwzakdnv/

```
= f.input :service_name, collection: @my_services, label_method: :service_name, value_method: :service_name, id: "service"

#service_will_show_here

javascript:
$('#service').change(function(){
  $selected_value=$('#service option:selected').text();
  $('#service_will_show_here').text($selected_value);
});
```

---

Here's the ERB of both dropdowns. The first dropdown works, but the second one doesn't

```
<select id="select1">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>

<%= f.input :service_name, collection: @my_services, label_method: :service_name, value_method: :service_name, id: "select2" %>

<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select1').change(function(){
      $selected_value=$('#select1 option:selected').text();
      $('#result1').text($selected_value);
    });

  $('#select2').change(function(){
    $selected_value=$('#select2 option:selected').text();
    $('#result2').text($selected_value);
  });
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with rails, but Javascript. BTW: If you're new to rails i would not recommend to use simple form..

Comment: Please add the raw HTML that is rendered from your Slim template to your question.

Comment: I added the ERB of a dropdown using HTML and another using Simple Form, but the latter doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that id: "select2" in Simple Form didn't override the generated id "service_name". Instead, input_html has to be used, so that the following works:

```
= f.input :service_name, collection: @my_services, input_html: {id: "select2"}
```

This was stated here: [Rails simple_form: custom input id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674333/rails-simple-form-custom-input-id)